# Can I add object to an array in a loop and then return the array in the same line?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have some simple ruby code where I create an Array, create a bunch of objects and push them into the array and then return the array

```
def create_barcodes(count)
  barcodes = Array.new
  count.times { barcodes.push(Barcode.create) }
  barcodes
end
```

It feels like there should be a way to reduce this to one or two lines and at a minimum avoid having to reference the `barcodes` array at the end so it gets returned. Is there some clever way to get the count loop to return the array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
barcodes = Array.new(count){ Barcode.create }
```

Comment: Several good answers but this is the best. I can even drop the variable at this point so very concise

Answer (score 8):

Try to the following:

```
count.times.map { Barcode.create }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_barcodes(count)
  barcodes = (1..count).map { Barcode.create }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current example you don't need to instantiate a new array - just use the `map` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Also if you find yourself in a situation that you have to instantiate a new array, fill it up with data and then return it I would suggest using the `tap` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap).

In your case the code would look like:

```
Array.new.tap do |barcodes|
  count.times { barcodes.push(Barcode.create) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, lazy instantiation of any amount of the `Barcodes`:

```
[->() { Barcode.create }].cycle.take(count).map(&:call)
```

Comment: Haha I definitely wouldn't use it but it's very interesting! thanks for the suggestion.